# Toggle the position(in pagestructure) of HTML Element

Tags: javascript, html, css

lets say i have 3 Elements like that:

```
<h1>Hello</h1>
<p>hello</p>
<h1>Hello</h1>
```

I want to get rid of the second `<h1>` because i only want to have once per page. But i want to be able to change the position of the `<h1>`. For mobile View it should be displayed bellow the `<p>` and for desktop above. I know its possible with bootstrap/display:none; but like i said i want to change the position of only one `<h1>` depending on the pages scaling.

Many Thanks for helping

Comment: See this [CSS media queries tutorial](https://css-tricks.com/a-complete-guide-to-css-media-queries/). Read about the [:nth-child](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/n/nth-child/) selector to select a specific `h1` headline.

Comment: Actually you should not have *two* `<h1>` and hide one; you should have just *one* `<h1>` and change its position depending on whether you are on mobile or not or, to be more accurate, depending on the page width. It can be done in a number of ways, using just HTML and CSS (no need to use Bootstrap and no JavaScript required). I suggest you look into CSS grid-system and CSS flexbox and you look at CSS media queries too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this via flex or grid. Below is example of flex. If you want to keep only two items i.e. `<h1> and <p>` in a container, then in the media query you can simply set `flex-direction: column-reverse;` instead of changing order of `<h1> and <p>`.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.heading {
  order: 1;
}
.text {
  order: 2;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .heading {
    order: 2;
  }
  .text {
    order: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
</head>
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <h1 class="heading">Hello</h1>
    <p class="text">hello</p>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

try with `order` & `media query`

```css
@media(max-width:767px){
  .title-section{
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:column;
  }
  h1 { 
    order: 2;
    }  
  p {
     order: 1; 
  }
  
}
```

```html
<div class="title-section">
<h1>Hello Heading Tag</h1>
<p>hello P Tag</p>
</div>
```